# Why a java property not working when starts with "!"?

Tags: java, properties

I tried this properties file:

```
# test config

# global configuration
!title=Test report
!background=fff

query=...
paramSource=...
```

but `!param` and `!background` are never read.

Why?

Comment: Why ask questions that you answer yourself within the same minute?

Comment: @Qiau It is not looked down upon to answer your own question, even if you know the answer before asking. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: @JoshMein: I agree, but the "question" is pretty trivial.. I suppose you think it's ok to ask why lines that start with # isn't executed in a bash script too?

Comment: @Qiau This question may very well be bad use of self answering of questions; however, your comment makes it seem that SO looks down upon answering your own question in general when it is actually encouraged.

Comment: @JoshMein: You are right, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

> A comment line has an ASCII '#' or '!' as its first non-white space character

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a special character for create a **comment** and will be ignored.

Comment: Why are you downvoting his own answer? Either we wanted to create an entry for people to share this problem - or he found out quickly afterwards.

Comment: @Baz It is not looked down upon to answer your own question, even if you know the answer before asking. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: You barely asked and you immediately answer it. It seems to me that you should have researched more.

Comment: @JoshMein Yes, but this should only be used if it's a non trivial problem.

Comment: I can't; StackOverflow said: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days.", and I answer because it is encouraged to share knowledge! See, when you write a question, there's a check: "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style".

Comment: @Baz I don't think is trivial: I lost half day to understand why doesn't work and this problem isn't on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @g.annunziata Took me 2 seconds to google "java properties special characters"

Comment: @Baz yes, on Google > Wikipedia. Not in Stack Overflow. This is why I shared.

Comment: @g.annunziata Anyways, I would suggest accepting the answer of Peter Lawrey, since it contains a link to the Javadoc for reference.